# Stepping thru a DAO.Recordset - skips past the first 2540 records - Huh?

Tags: vba, ms-access

Seems a straightforward enough task, but I am seeing an odd result.

1) The Recordset is based on a valid query that returns 2739 records

2) When I `.MoveFirst` then step thru with `.MoveNext`, sending output to debug.print, the loop seems to be skipping the first 2540 records.  The Index numbers align with the ID values from my query.

3) The simplified code below reaches the EOF as expected

Any suggestions what might be happening?

```
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim n As Integer
Dim db As Database

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("myQuery")

n = 0

With rs1
    .MoveFirst
    Do Until .EOF
        n = n + 1
        Debug.Print n & " - " & .Fields("INPUT_ID")
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With
```

The debug results look like this:

```
2541 - 26023261
2542 - 26023262
2543 - 26023263
<<snip>>
2737 - 26023457
2738 - 26023458
2739 - 26023459
```

What happened to rows 1 thru 2540?

Comment: Yes, both of these return "2739" as expected.

Comment: Looking at the query results, there are no oddities, especially near record 2540...

Comment: After Loop, n = 2739

Comment: Oddly, "Debug.Print .Fields("DESC").Value" returns 199 records (rather than the expected 2739).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate window has a line limit of 199. So it's only displaying the last 199 line results of your code.

Comment: Ouch!  Did not expect that.  In my current (real) function I was stepping thru a PAIR of tables (one a subset of records of the other).  I was seeing an unexpected EOF error which seemed to be supported by the missing rows in the debug window.

Going back to revisit that issue.

Thanks